# как обновить картинку в imageView

Tags: android, android-imageview

Такой вопрос, гружу в приложение картинку на сервер, в методе `onActivityResult()` получаю ссылку на новую загруженную картинку, вставляю ссылку через piccaso, но картинка не обновляется.

вот код:

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

            photo1 = data.getStringExtra("nameAva1");
            photo1=("http://xn--24-vlchqgky.xn--p1ai/images/avatars/upload/"+photo1);
      if(requestCode==1){
        Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                  .load(R.drawable.user_images)
                  .placeholder(R.drawable.user_images)
                  .error(R.drawable.user_images)
                  .into(image1);
          Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                  .load(photo1)
                  .placeholder(R.drawable.user_images)
                  .error(R.drawable.user_images)
                  .into(image1);


      }else if(requestCode==2){
          photo2=data.getStringExtra("avaPhoto2");
          photo2=("http://xn--24-vlchqgky.xn--p1ai/images/avatars/upload/"+photo2);

          Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(photo2.toString())
                  .placeholder(R.drawable.user_images)
                  .error(R.drawable.user_images)
                  .into(image2);
      }else if(requestCode==3){

          photo3=data.getStringExtra("avaPhoto3");
          photo3=("http://xn--24-vlchqgky.xn--p1ai/images/avatars/upload/"+photo3);
          Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(photo3)
                  .placeholder(R.drawable.user_images)
                  .error(R.drawable.user_images)
                  .into(image3);
      }

        Log.d("img","upload photo1 === "+photo1+"   photo 2  "+photo2+"  avaphoto3 ==  "+photo3);
        Log.d("img","requestCode === "+requestCode);

    }
```

проблема в том, что ссылка на картинку приходит обновленная, а вот в `ImageView` она вставляется только при первой загрузке , при последующих загрузках картинка не обновляется. Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: У вас что-то странное в коде - 3 разных ImageView, и в первую дважды картинка загружается, причём разная.

Comment: ну 3 картинки в профиле грузится у каждого свой загрузчик , и в resault приходит обновленная ссылка с новой загруженной картинкой , все работает как надо но вот после загрузки не обновляется картинка а остается старая может проблема в кэш

Comment: Попробуйте через postDelayed запускать скачивание картинки - в onActivityResult многие вещи себя странно ведут.

Comment: можно пример кода пожалуйста)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Picasso удерживает переданный ему `ImageView` для осуществления с ним всех заданных Вами манипуляций. Вам необходимо перед осуществлением новых манипуляций отменить предыдущие:

```
Picasso.with(context).cancelRequest(image1);
```

Также немаловажный факт, что Picasso хранит все скачанные изображения в кеше по ключу - ссылке на скачиваемое изображение. Это значит, что если изображение по ссылке поменялось, а сама ссылка нет, то нужно сказать Picasso, что данный ключ больше не действителен, иначе он будет брать старое изображение, а за новым по ссылке не пойдёт:

```
Picasso.with(context).invalidate(photo1);
```

Если при этом новое изображение в `ImageView` не вставляется, попробуйте вычистить из него старый `Bitmap`:

```
Drawable drawable = image1.getDrawable();
if (drawable != null) {
    ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap().recycle();
}
```

А потом осуществляйте новые манипуляции с `ImageView`:

```
Picasso.with(context)
    .load(photo1)
    .placeholder(R.drawable.user_images)
    .into(image1);
```

Comment: то что два раза используется так я пытался очистить как раз картинку что бы ее обновить , тоже не помогло  , пробывал так же   ИМЯ_АКТИВМТИ.this, тоже особых изменений не произошло , пробывал чистить как написано выше Drawable drawable = yourImageView.getDrawable();
if (drawable != null) {
    ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap().recycle();
}

Comment: падает приложение с такой ошибкой :

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               Process: , PID: 12951
                                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap android.graphics.Bitmap@199c2ae2

Comment: с учетом полученного Вами Exception, заглянул в саму библиотеку и исправил ответ. Надеюсь поможет.

Comment: Picasso.with(profile.this).cancelRequest(image1); пробывал и так тоже не помогает фотка не обнавляется ( , так же пробывал менять ее в onResume и тоже самое не обновляется , закрыть все приложение и заново открыть то картинка будет обновленная

Comment: Picasso.with(context).invalidate(photo1); вроде помогло ))) спасибо за помощь )))

Answer (score 0):

В `onActivityResult` многие вещи себя странно ведут. Т.е. активити и её контекст находятся "в подвешенном" состоянии. В этом случае можно попробовать заставить код исполниться в очереди исполнения "нормальной", в т.ч. с некоторой задержкой чтобы успела активити в "себя прийти" (задержка может быть и не нужна).

Сделать это можно методами `View#post(Runnable run)` и `View#postDelayed(Runnable run, int delay)` так:

```
image2.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
      //тут код выполнится в нормальном состоянии активити с задержкой в 300 мс
      Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(photo2)
              .placeholder(R.drawable.user_images)
              .error(R.drawable.user_images)
              .into(image2);
   }
}, 300);
```

Comment: попробывал тоже самое (( картинка так и не сменилась на новую , припервой загрузке картинка меняется , если пытаюсь заменить то картинка не меняется

Comment: @dimasta68, а если попробовать `this` вместо `getApplicationContext()`?

Comment: this подчеркивает красным пробывал так же getApplication()  тоже самое (

Comment: Попробуйте ИМЯ_АКТИВМТИ.this

Answer (score 0):

Отлично загружает картинку в ImageView

```
public void onClick(View v) {
new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1))
            .execute("http://java.sogeti.nl/JavaBlog/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/android_icon_256.png");

}

private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

Не забудь в AndroidManifest.xml прописать разрешение на доступ в интернет:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```